# Java implementation of JavaStreamingContext.fileStream

Tags: java, streaming, filestream, apache-spark

I have some trouble of programming with spark streaming. As I want to create a input stream and read them using self-defined input format. The definition looks like this:

```
def fileStream[K, V, F <: NewInputFormat[K, V]](
      directory: String): JavaPairInputDStream[K, V] = {
    implicit val cmk: ClassTag[K] =
      implicitly[ClassTag[AnyRef]].asInstanceOf[ClassTag[K]]
    implicit val cmv: ClassTag[V] =
      implicitly[ClassTag[AnyRef]].asInstanceOf[ClassTag[V]]
    implicit val cmf: ClassTag[F] =
      implicitly[ClassTag[AnyRef]].asInstanceOf[ClassTag[F]]
    ssc.fileStream[K, V, F](directory)
}
```

If I'm using scala, then I will write my code as below:

```
val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](dataDirectory)
```

But, when I'm using java like this:

```
ClassTag<LongWritable> k = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(LongWritable.class);
ClassTag<Text> v = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Text.class);
ClassTag<InputFormat<LongWritable, Text>> f = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(TextInputFormat.class);
JavaPairInputDStream<LongWritable, Text> inputLines = ssc.fileStream<k, v, f>("dataDirectory);
```

I will come across the errors of "**fileStream cannot be resolved or is not a field**".
So, how to use JavaStreamingContext.fileStream?

I created ssc with the code below:

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Streaming Demo"), new Duration(3000));
```

Thanks!

Comment: When I was searching for this problem in the Internet, I found somebody wrote their code as below:

`JavaPairInputDStream<LongWritable, Text> inputLines = ssc.<LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat>fileStream(dataDirectory);`

So, I tried, but not work at all.

One interesting thing is that [cgrothaus](https://github.com/cgrothaus/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/test/java/spark/streaming/JavaAPISuite.java) supply **testFileStream** function, however, [apache](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/test/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/JavaAPISuite.java) does not-_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **fileStream cannot be resolved or is not a field** problem is caused by improper using of `fileStream`. When using `fileStream` as below:

```
JavaPairInputDStream<LongWritable, Text> inputLines = ssc.<LongWritable, Text, TestInputFormat>fileStream(dataDirectory);
```

and `TestInputFormat` must extends `OutputFormat<LongWritable, Text>`.

```
public interface TestOutputFormat extends OutputFormat<LongWritable, Text>
```

There is no problem when using in this way, but you have to implement the Class of TestInputFormat Using **old API(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*)**. and I have not tried this. ^_^

Answer (score -1):

You need to add

```
import java.io.File;
```

or

```
import java.io.*;
```